# Percent Total Pandas Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

Hi I have a Pandas Matrix that I need to find percents on. 
The goal is to find how much a user has used a product on a date. Basically to find on what date, did this user use what % of the category.

[What I got Excel to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXb94.png)
I got this work in Excel by taking the count of each individual user's appearance in the category and dividing it by the count of total ID's for the category

I have no idea how to represent this in Pandas or how to work it to look up how to do it in the Documentation. Can you help me get something like this in a Pandas Matrix?

fields I am working with: 
'Category', 'ID', 'User', 'Occurred On'

**It's not much because I am so stuck, So far, I have:**

```
func = lambda x: 100*x.count()/df.shape[1]

counts = df.pivot_table(index=["Category", 'User', 'ID'], values = ["Occurred On"], aggfunc=func, margins=True, fill_value=0)
print(counts)
```

Can someone point me to the right direction of what I need to read in the documentation or other posts here to understand how to do the math on this matrix?

**Edit #1:**   Data frame looks something like this:

```
 TextFileReader = pd.read_csv(csv_input, sep=',',  names = ['Category', 'ID', 'User', 'Occurred On'])

lookup = pd.read_csv('lookup.csv', sep=',')
df= pd.merge(lookup, keep, left_on='user', right_on='user', how='inner')
```

Data Frame Output:

```
Category                                                        User       ID #Count      Occurred On #%
Category 1 ___________________...                              1@work.com  1543841       16.666667
                                                                           1543842       16.666667
                                                                           1543843       16.666667
                                                                           1543844       16.666667
                                                                           1543845       16.666667
                                                                           1543846       16.666667
                                                                           1543847       16.666667
                                                                           1543848       16.666667
                                                                           1543849       16.666667
                                                                           1543850       16.666667
                                                                           1543851       16.666667
                                                                           1543852       16.666667
                                                                           1543853       16.666667
                                                                           1543854       16.666667
                                                                           1543855       16.666667
                                                                           1543856       16.666667
                                                                           1543857       16.666667
                                                                           1543858       16.666667
                                                                           1543859       16.666667
                                                                           1543860       16.666667
                                                                           1543861       16.666667
                                                                           1543862       16.666667
                                                                           1543863       16.666667
Category2 ...                                                   b@work.com 6064691       16.666667
                                                                           6064692       16.666667
                                                                           6064693       16.666667
                                                                           6064694       16.666667
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Show us your dataframe or pandas matrix and what you expect it to be.

Comment: @MohitMotwani I added some edits. I hope this helps. I am doing the best I can with obfuscated data.